# Do Weapon Focus and & Weapon Specialization work with ray spells?

Tags: starfinder

Do Weapon Focus and & Weapon Specialization work with ray spells

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### No, it doesn't

Unlike pathfinder, *rays* are not a valid choice for [Weapon Focus](http://www.starjammersrd.com/feats/combat-feats/weapon-focus-combat/), as the wording on the feat is different, and it requires a *weapon type*:

> Chose one **weapon type** (small arms, longarms, heavy weapons, etc.).

[Weapon types](http://www.starjammersrd.com/equipment/weapons/#Weapon_Types) are well defined in the system, and are as follows:

- Basic Melee
- Advanced Melee
- Small Arms
- Longarms
- Heavy Weapons
- Sniper Weapons
- Ammunitions & Grenades
- Solarian Weapon Crystals

As you can see, *rays* are not listed there, in fact, I don't think rays are even a thing in Starfinder, as none of the spells that target EAC or KAC actually say anything about being rays.